# Fastest way to read a CSV file java

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, data-structures, reader

I´ve been trying to read several csv files (arround 20 MB) using openCSV, but so far it has been slow. Im trying to read 4 csv files which I´m loading into a heap, which I have designed. I was wondering, if there is any other way this could be done in a lot less time.

```
private Heap<VOMovingViolations> datosHeap; 

public void loadMovingViolations()
{
    Runtime garbage = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
    garbage.gc();
    try 
    {
        FileReader fileReaderMes1 = new FileReader(FECHAS[0]);
        FileReader fileReaderMes2 = new FileReader(FECHAS[1]); 
        FileReader fileReaderMes3 = new FileReader(FECHAS[2]); 
        FileReader fileReaderMes4 = new FileReader(FECHAS[3]); 
        CSVReader enero = new CSVReaderBuilder(fileReaderMes1).withSkipLines(1).build();
        CSVReader febrero = new CSVReaderBuilder(fileReaderMes2).withSkipLines(1).build();
        CSVReader marzo = new CSVReaderBuilder(fileReaderMes3).withSkipLines(1).build();
        CSVReader abril = new CSVReaderBuilder(fileReaderMes4).withSkipLines(1).build();

        String[] row; 


        while((row = enero.readNext()) != null)
        {
            int objectId = Integer.parseInt(row[0]); 
            int totalPaid = (int)Double.parseDouble(row[9]);
            short fi = Short.parseShort(row[8]);
            short penalty1 = Short.parseShort(row[10]);
            datosHeap.insert(new VOMovingViolations(objectId, totalPaid,  fi,  row[2], row[13],
                        row[12],row[14], row[15], row[4], row[3], penalty1));
        }

        while((row = febrero.readNext()) != null)
        {
            int objectId = Integer.parseInt(row[0]); 
            int totalPaid = (int)Double.parseDouble(row[9]);
            short fi = Short.parseShort(row[8]);
            short penalty1 = Short.parseShort(row[10]);
            datosHeap.insert(new VOMovingViolations(objectId, totalPaid,  fi,  row[2], row[13],
                        row[12],row[14], row[15], row[4], row[3], penalty1));
        }

        while((row = marzo.readNext()) != null)
        {
            int objectId = Integer.parseInt(row[0]); 
            int totalPaid = (int)Double.parseDouble(row[9]);
            short fi = Short.parseShort(row[8]);
            short penalty1 = Short.parseShort(row[10]);
            datosHeap.insert(new VOMovingViolations(objectId, totalPaid,  fi,  row[2], row[13],
                        row[12],row[14], row[15], row[4], row[3], penalty1));
        }

        while((row = abril.readNext()) != null)
        {
            int objectId = Integer.parseInt(row[0]); 
            int totalPaid = (int)Double.parseDouble(row[9]);
            short fi = Short.parseShort(row[8]);
            short penalty1 = Short.parseShort(row[10]);
            datosHeap.insert(new VOMovingViolations(objectId, totalPaid,  fi,  row[2], row[13],
                        row[12],row[14], row[15], row[4], row[3], penalty1));
        }

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}
```

I would really appreciate any help or any idea someone could please give me.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Have you heard of methods? They are great for reusing code, instead of repeating it 4 times. You should learn about the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: *"it has been slow"* How slow? Why do you think it can be faster?

Comment: Sorry for the mess in the code. It´s taking about 2 seconds to load all four files. I think it could be faster if I load the files using a thread and parallelizing the process, but so far I haven´t found anything helpful.

Comment: @SantiagoFajardo A parallel reading of files might have a negative effect on the speed, because in your case probably the IO is the bottleneck and not the CPU. If the data cannot be cached or the file size reduced, show the user a progress bar (assuming there is a UI).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## tl;dr

Reading a 20 MB CSV file, and instantiating an object per row, takes **less than 1 second** in total elapsed time.

## Details

You did not define the term “slow”. So I did an experiment, a casual benchmark test.

First we create a 20 MB file of 40,000 `Person` records. Each `Person` holds a first & last name in French, a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), and some arbitrary text as a description. The data is written as four columns in a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). I used the [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library to write and read.

Secondly, this written file is read. Each row of data is read into memory, then used to instantiate and collect a `Person` object.

Reading this file, and instantiating `Person` object for each row took **less than one second in total elapsed time**. Each row takes about 20K [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Actually, this includes reading the file *twice*, as we do a scan to count the number of rows of data to set initial capacity of the collected instances. Also, we are parsing a hex string input into the 128-bit value of a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), so we have some time spent on data-processing (not just reading).

For Java 16+, define `Person` class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). We override [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) to avoid printing out the long `description` content.

```
record Person ( String givenName , String surname , UUID id , String description ) 
{
    static public  String LOREM_IPSUM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "Person{ " +
                "givenName='" + givenName + '\'' +
                " | surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                " | id='" + id + '\'' +
                " }";
    }
}
```

For earlier Java, write a conventional `Person` class.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Person
{
    // Static
   static public  String LOREM_IPSUM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

    // Member variables.
    public String givenName, surname, description;
    public UUID id;

    public Person ( String givenName , String surname , UUID id , String description )
    {
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "Person{ " +
                "givenName='" + givenName + '\'' +
                " | surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                " | id='" + id + '\'' +
                " }";
    }
}
```

And here is the complete app that writes and then reads the 20 MB file. Please study and critique, as I whipped this up in a jiffy. I’ve not double-checked my work.

You will find a `write` method, and a `read` method. The `main` method calls both, and tracks time.

```
package work.basil.example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class CsvSpeed
{
    public List < Person > read ( Path path )
    {
        // TODO: Add a check for valid file existing.

        List < Person > list = List.of();  // Default to empty list.
        try
        {
            // Prepare list.
            int initialCapacity = ( int ) Files.lines( path ).count();
            list = new ArrayList <>( initialCapacity );

            // Read CSV file. For each row, instantiate and collect `DailyProduct`.
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader( path );
            Iterable < CSVRecord > records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse( reader );
            for ( CSVRecord record : records )
            {
                String givenName = record.get( "givenName" );
                String surname = record.get( "surname" );
                UUID id = UUID.fromString( record.get( "id" ) );
                String description = record.get( "description" );
                // Instantiate `Person` object, and collect it.
                Person person = new Person( givenName , surname , id , description );
                list.add( person );
            }
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void write ( final Path path )
    {
        ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        try ( final CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader( "givenName" , "surname" , "id" , "description" ).print( path , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ; )
        {
            int limit = 40_000;  // 40_000 yields about 20 MB of data.
            List < String > givenNames = List.of( "Adrien" , "Aimon" , "Alerion" , "Alexis" , "Alezan" , "Ancil" , "Andre" , "Antoine" , "Archard" , "Aurélien" , "Averill" , "Baptiste" , "Barnard" , "Bartelemy" , "Bastien" , "Baylee" , "Beale" , "Beau" , "Beaumont" , "Beauregard" , "Bellamy" , "Berger" , "Blaize" , "Blondel" , "Boyce" , "Bruce" , "Brunelle" , "Brys" , "Burcet" , "Burnell" , "Burrell" , "Byron" , "Canaan" , "Carden" , "Carolas" , "Cavell" , "Chace" , "Chanler" , "Chante" , "Chappel" , "Charles" , "Chasen" , "Chason" , "Chemin" , "Chene" , "Cher" , "Chevalier" , "Cheyne" , "Clément" , "Clemence" , "Corbin" , "Coty" , "Cygne" , "Damien" , "Dandre" , "Dariel" , "Darl" , "Dauphine" , "Davet" , "Dax" , "Dean" , "Delice" , "Delmon" , "Destin" , "Dominique" , "Donatien" , "Duke" , "Eliott" , "Elroy" , "Enzo" , "Erwan" , "Etalon" , "Ethan" , "Fabron" , "Ferrand" , "Filberte" , "Florent" , "Florian" , "Fontaine" , "Forest" , "Fortune" , "Franchot" , "Francois" , "Fraser" , "Frayne" , "Gaëtan" , "Gabin" , "Gage" , "Gaige" , "Garland" , "Garner" , "Gaston" , "Gauge" , "Gaylord" , "Germain" , "Germaine" , "German" , "Gervaise" , "Giles" , "Gilles" , "Gitan" , "Grosvener" , "Guifford" , "Guion" , "Guy" , "Guzman" , "Henri" , "Holland" , "Hugo" , "Hugues" , "Hyacinthe" , "Jérémy" , "Jacquan" , "Jacques" , "Jacquez" , "Janvier" , "Jardan" , "Jay" , "Jaye" , "Jehan" , "Jemond" , "Jocquez" , "Jonathan" , "Jules" , "Julien" , "Justus" , "Karoly" , "Lado" , "Lafayette" , "Lamond" , "Lancelin" , "Landis" , "Landry" , "Laron" , "Larrimore" , "Laurent" , "LaValle" , "Leandre" , "Leggett" , "Leonce" , "Leron" , "Leverett" , "Lilian" , "Loïc" , "Lorenzo" , "Louis" , "Lowell" , "Luc" , "Lucien" , "Lukas" , "Macaire" , "Mace" , "Mahieu" , "Maison" , "Malleville" , "Manneville" , "Mantel" , "Marc" , "Marcel" , "Marion" , "Marius" , "Markez" , "Markis" , "Marmion" , "Marquis" , "Marquise" , "Marshall" , "Martial" , "Maslin" , "Mason" , "Matheo" , "Mathias" , "Mathys" , "Matthieu" , "Maxence" , "Mayson" , "Mehdi" , "Merle" , "Merville" , "Montague" , "Montaigu" , "Monte" , "Montgomery" , "Montreal" , "Montrel" , "Moore" , "Morel" , "Mortimer" , "Nerville" , "Neuveville" , "Nicolas" , "Noë" , "Noah" , "Noe" , "Norman" , "Norville" , "Nouel" , "Olivier" , "Onfroi" , "Paien" , "Parfait" , "Parnell" , "Pascal" , "Patrice" , "Paul" , "Peppin" , "Percival" , "Percy" , "Pernell" , "Peverell" , "Philipe" , "Pierpont" , "Pierre" , "Pomeroy" , "Prewitt" , "Purvis" , "Quennell" , "Quentin" , "Quincey" , "Quincy" , "Quintin" , "Rémi" , "Rafaelle" , "Ranger" , "Raoul" , "Raphaël" , "Rapier" , "Rawlins" , "Ray" , "Raynard" , "Remi" , "René" , "Renard" , "Rene" , "Reule" , "Reynard" , "Robin" , "Romain" , "Rondel" , "Roy" , "Royal" , "Ruff" , "Rush" , "Russel" , "Rustin" , "Sabastien" , "Sacha" , "Salomon" , "Samuel" , "Satordi" , "Saville" , "Scoville" , "Sebastien" , "Sennett" , "Severin" , "Shant" , "Shantae" , "Sidney" , "Siffre" , "Simeon" , "Simon" , "Sinclair" , "Sofiane" , "Somer" , "Stephane" , "Sully" , "Sydney" , "Sylvain" , "Talbot" , "Talon" , "Telford" , "Tempest" , "Teppo" , "Théo" , "Thayer" , "Thibault" , "Thibaut" , "Thiery" , "Tiennan" , "Tiennot" , "Titouan" , "Toussaint" , "Travaris" , "Tyson" , "Urson" , "Vachel" , "Valentin" , "Valere" , "Vallis" , "Verdun" , "Victoir" , "Victor" , "Waltier" , "William" , "Wyatt" , "Yanis" , "Yann" , "Yves" , "Yvon" , "Zosime" , "Abrial" , "Abrielle" , "Abril" , "Adele" , "Alair" , "Alerion" , "Amee" , "Angelique" , "Annette" , "Antonella" , "Arian" , "Ariane" , "Armandina" , "Aubree" , "Aubrielle" , "Audra" , "Avril" , "Bella" , "Berneta" , "Bette" , "Blaise" , "Blanche" , "Blasa" , "Bonte" , "Brie" , "Brienne" , "Brigit" , "Cachay" , "Calice" , "Camille" , "Camylle" , "Caprice" , "Caressa" , "Caroline" , "Catin" , "Celesta" , "Celeste" , "Cera" , "Cerise" , "Chablis" , "Chalice" , "Chambray" , "Champagne" , "Chandell" , "Chaney" , "Chantal" , "Chante" , "Chanterelle" , "Chantile" , "Chantilly" , "Chantrice" , "Charla" , "Charlotte" , "Charmane" , "Chaton" , "Chemin" , "Chenetta" , "Cher" , "Chere" , "Cheri" , "Cheryl" , "Christine" , "Cidney" , "Cinderella" , "Claire" , "Claudette" , "Colette" , "Cordelle" , "Cydnee" , "Daeja" , "Daija" , "Daja" , "Damzel" , "Darelle" , "Darlene" , "Darselle" , "Dejanelle" , "Deleena" , "Delice" , "Demeri" , "Deni" , "Denise" , "Desgracias" , "Desire" , "Desiree" , "Destanee" , "Destiny" , "Dior" , "Domanique" , "Dominique" , "Elaina" , "Elaine" , "Elayna" , "Elise" , "Eloisa" , "Elyse" , "Emeline" , "Emmaline" , "Emmeline" , "Estella" , "Estrella" , "Etiennette" , "Evette" , "Fabienne" , "Fabrienne" , "Fanchon" , "Fancy" , "Fawna" , "Fayana" , "Fayette" , "Fifi" , "Fleur" , "Fleurette" , "Fontanna" , "Fosette" , "Francine" , "Frederique" , "Gabriel" , "Gabriele" , "Gabrielle" , "Gaby" , "Garcelle" , "Gena" , "Genie" , "Georgette" , "Germaine" , "Gervaise" , "Gitana" , "Harriet" , "Heloisa" , "Holland" , "Honnetta" , "Isabelle" , "Ivette" , "Ivonne" , "Jacqueena" , "Jacquetta" , "Jacquiline" , "Jacyline" , "Jaime" , "Jakqueline" , "Janeen" , "Janelly" , "Janina" , "Janiqua" , "Janique" , "Jannnelle" , "Jaquita" , "Jardena" , "Jeanetta" , "Jermaine" , "Jessamine" , "Jewel" , "Jewell" , "Joli" , "Jolie" , "Josephine" , "Jozephine" , "Julieta" , "Karessa" , "Karmaine" , "Klara" , "Laine" , "Lanelle" , "Laramie" , "Layne" , "Layney" , "Leala" , "Leonette" , "Lissette" , "Lizette" , "Lourdes" , "Lucienne" , "Ly" , "Lyla" , "Lysette" , "Madelaine" , "Malerie" , "Manette" , "Marais" , "Marcelle" , "Marché" , "Mardi" , "Margo" , "Marguerite" , "Marie" , "Marie Claude" , "Marie Frances" , "Marie Joelle" , "Marie Pascale" , "Marie Sophie" , "Marjolaine" , "Marquise" , "Marvella" , "Mathieu" , "Matisse" , "Maurelle" , "Maurissa" , "Mavis" , "Melisande" , "Michelle" , "Miette" , "Mignon" , "Mimi" , "Mirya" , "Monet" , "Moniqua" , "Monteen" , "Musetta" , "Myrlie" , "Nadeen" , "Nadia" , "Nadiyah" , "Naeva" , "Nanon" , "Natalle" , "Naudia" , "Nettie" , "Nicholas" , "Nicki" , "Nicky" , "Nicole" , "Nicolette" , "Nicolina" , "Nicolle" , "Nikolette" , "Ninette" , "Ninon" , "Noelle" , "Nycole" , "Odelette" , "Opaline" , "Orane" , "Orva" , "Page" , "Parisa" , "Parnel" , "Parris" , "Patrice" , "Peridot" , "Pippi" , "Prairie" , "Rachele" , "Rachelle" , "Racquel" , "Raphaelle" , "Raquelle" , "Remi" , "Renée" , "Renea" , "Renelle" , "Renita" , "Risette" , "Rochelle" , "Romy" , "Rosabel" , "Rosiclara" , "Ruba" , "Russhell" , "Saleena" , "Salina" , "Satin" , "Sedona" , "Serene" , "Shandelle" , "Shanta" , "Shante" , "Shariah" , "Sharita" , "Sharleen" , "Sheree" , "Shereen" , "Sherell" , "Sherice" , "Sherry" , "Sidnee" , "Sidney" , "Sidnie" , "Sidonie" , "Sinclaire" , "Solange" , "Solen" , "Sorrel" , "Suzette" , "Sydnee" , "Sydney" , "Tallis" , "Tempest" , "Toinette" , "Turquoise" , "Veronique" , "Vignette" , "Villette" , "Violeta" , "Virginie" , "Voleta" , "Vonny" );
            List < String > surnames = List.of( "Arceneau" , "Aucoin" , "Babin" , "Babineaux" , "Benoit" , "Bergeron" , "Bernard" , "Bertrand" , "Bessette" , "Blanc" , "Blanchard" , "Bonnet" , "Boucher" , "Bourg" , "Bourque" , "Boutin" , "Bouvier" , "Braud" , "Broussard" , "Brun" , "Chevalier" , "David" , "Depaul" , "Desmarais" , "Disney" , "Dubois" , "Dupont" , "Dupuis" , "Durand" , "Fortescue" , "Fournier" , "Garnier" , "Gaudet" , "Gillet" , "Gillette" , "Girard" , "Gravois" , "Grosvenor" , "Lambert" , "Landry" , "Laroche" , "Laurent" , "Lefevre" , "Leroy" , "Leveque" , "Lisle" , "Martin" , "Michel" , "Molyneux" , "Moreau" , "Morel" , "Neville" , "Pelletier" , "Petit" , "Prideux" , "Renard" , "Richard" , "Robert" , "Rousseau" , "Roux" , "Rufus" , "Simon" , "Thomas" );
            for ( int i = 1 ; i <= limit ; i++ )
            {
                String givenName = givenNames.get( random.nextInt( 0 , givenNames.size() ) );
                String surname = surnames.get( random.nextInt( 0 , surnames.size() ) );
                UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
                String description = Person.LOREM_IPSUM;
                printer.printRecord( givenName , surname , id , description );
            }
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        // Launch the app.
        CsvSpeed app = new CsvSpeed();

        // Write.
        String when = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).toString().replace( ":" , "•" );
        Path pathOutput = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/persons.csv" );
        app.write( pathOutput );
        System.out.println( "Writing file: " + pathOutput );

        // Read.
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Path pathInput = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/persons.csv" );
        List < Person > list = app.read( pathInput );
        long stop = System.nanoTime();

        // Time.
        long elapsed = ( stop - start );
        Duration d = Duration.ofNanos( elapsed );
        System.out.println( "Reading elapsed: " + d );
        System.out.println( "Reading took nanos per row: " + ( elapsed / list.size() ) );
        System.out.println( "nanos elapsed: " + elapsed + "  |  list.size: " + list.size() );
    }
}
```

When run:

> Writing file: /Users/basilbourque/persons.csv
>
> Reading elapsed: PT0.857816234S
>
> Reading took nanos per row: 21445
>
> nanos elapsed: 857816234  |  list.size: 40000

Technology stack:

- Java 11.0.2 — *Zulu* by Azul Systems (built from OpenJDK)
- Run inside IntelliJ 2019.1
- [macOS Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/macOS_Mojave)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
- Processor: 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 (4 cores, 8 hyper)
- 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Storage: Solid-state built-in by Apple

Comment: I used your code and example data to create similar solution with [`Jackson CSV Dataformat API`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv). Thanks for great source pattern!

Comment: Thanks, I also used your example to create a solution with [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial)

Answer (score 5):

On [csv-parsers-comparison](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) we can find comparison between `CSV` `Reader`/`Writer`-s. The fastest is [`uniVocity CSV parser`](https://www.univocity.com/). Third is [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv) which I personally prefer. Using `@Basil Bourque` great example I changed it a little bit and used `Jackson` classes. Method read returns `MappingIterator` which you can use to initialise your heap object (see how I added elements to `List`). I did not include time details but you can do it yourself using Basil's and this solution:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class CsvSpeed {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File csvFile = new File("./resource/persons.csv").getAbsoluteFile();

        CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder()
                .addColumn("givenName")
                .addColumn("surname")
                .addColumn("id")
                .addColumn("description")
                .build().withHeader();

        CsvSpeed csvSpeed = new CsvSpeed();
        csvSpeed.write(csvFile, schema);

        // Read.
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        MappingIterator<Person> personMappingIterator = csvSpeed.read(csvFile, schema);
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(40_000);
        personMappingIterator.forEachRemaining(persons::add);

        long stop = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(persons.size());

        // Time.
        long elapsed = (stop - start);
        Duration d = Duration.ofNanos(elapsed);
        System.out.println("Reading elapsed: " + d);
        System.out.println("Reading took nanos per row: " + (elapsed / persons.size()));
        System.out.println("nanos elapsed: " + elapsed + "  |  list.size: " + persons.size());
    }

    public MappingIterator<Person> read(final File path, CsvSchema schema) throws Exception {
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

        ObjectReader reader = csvMapper.readerFor(Person.class).with(schema);
        return reader.readValues(path);
    }

    public void write(final File path, CsvSchema schema) throws Exception {
        ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        ObjectWriter writer = csvMapper.writerFor(Person.class).with(schema);

        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path)) {
            List<String> givenNames = Arrays.asList("Adrien", "Aimon", "Alerion", "Alexis", "Alezan", "Ancil", "Andre", "Antoine", "Archard", "Aurélien", "Averill", "Baptiste", "Barnard", "Bartelemy", "Bastien", "Baylee", "Beale", "Beau", "Beaumont", "Beauregard", "Bellamy", "Berger", "Blaize", "Blondel", "Boyce", "Bruce", "Brunelle", "Brys", "Burcet", "Burnell", "Burrell", "Byron", "Canaan", "Carden", "Carolas", "Cavell", "Chace", "Chanler", "Chante", "Chappel", "Charles", "Chasen", "Chason", "Chemin", "Chene", "Cher", "Chevalier", "Cheyne", "Clément", "Clemence", "Corbin", "Coty", "Cygne", "Damien", "Dandre", "Dariel", "Darl", "Dauphine", "Davet", "Dax", "Dean", "Delice", "Delmon", "Destin", "Dominique", "Donatien", "Duke", "Eliott", "Elroy", "Enzo", "Erwan", "Etalon", "Ethan", "Fabron", "Ferrand", "Filberte", "Florent", "Florian", "Fontaine", "Forest", "Fortune", "Franchot", "Francois", "Fraser", "Frayne", "Gaëtan", "Gabin", "Gage", "Gaige", "Garland", "Garner", "Gaston", "Gauge", "Gaylord", "Germain", "Germaine", "German", "Gervaise", "Giles", "Gilles", "Gitan", "Grosvener", "Guifford", "Guion", "Guy", "Guzman", "Henri", "Holland", "Hugo", "Hugues", "Hyacinthe", "Jérémy", "Jacquan", "Jacques", "Jacquez", "Janvier", "Jardan", "Jay", "Jaye", "Jehan", "Jemond", "Jocquez", "Jonathan", "Jules", "Julien", "Justus", "Karoly", "Lado", "Lafayette", "Lamond", "Lancelin", "Landis", "Landry", "Laron", "Larrimore", "Laurent", "LaValle", "Leandre", "Leggett", "Leonce", "Leron", "Leverett", "Lilian", "Loïc", "Lorenzo", "Louis", "Lowell", "Luc", "Lucien", "Lukas", "Macaire", "Mace", "Mahieu", "Maison", "Malleville", "Manneville", "Mantel", "Marc", "Marcel", "Marion", "Marius", "Markez", "Markis", "Marmion", "Marquis", "Marquise", "Marshall", "Martial", "Maslin", "Mason", "Matheo", "Mathias", "Mathys", "Matthieu", "Maxence", "Mayson", "Mehdi", "Merle", "Merville", "Montague", "Montaigu", "Monte", "Montgomery", "Montreal", "Montrel", "Moore", "Morel", "Mortimer", "Nerville", "Neuveville", "Nicolas", "Noë", "Noah", "Noe", "Norman", "Norville", "Nouel", "Olivier", "Onfroi", "Paien", "Parfait", "Parnell", "Pascal", "Patrice", "Paul", "Peppin", "Percival", "Percy", "Pernell", "Peverell", "Philipe", "Pierpont", "Pierre", "Pomeroy", "Prewitt", "Purvis", "Quennell", "Quentin", "Quincey", "Quincy", "Quintin", "Rémi", "Rafaelle", "Ranger", "Raoul", "Raphaël", "Rapier", "Rawlins", "Ray", "Raynard", "Remi", "René", "Renard", "Rene", "Reule", "Reynard", "Robin", "Romain", "Rondel", "Roy", "Royal", "Ruff", "Rush", "Russel", "Rustin", "Sabastien", "Sacha", "Salomon", "Samuel", "Satordi", "Saville", "Scoville", "Sebastien", "Sennett", "Severin", "Shant", "Shantae", "Sidney", "Siffre", "Simeon", "Simon", "Sinclair", "Sofiane", "Somer", "Stephane", "Sully", "Sydney", "Sylvain", "Talbot", "Talon", "Telford", "Tempest", "Teppo", "Théo", "Thayer", "Thibault", "Thibaut", "Thiery", "Tiennan", "Tiennot", "Titouan", "Toussaint", "Travaris", "Tyson", "Urson", "Vachel", "Valentin", "Valere", "Vallis", "Verdun", "Victoir", "Victor", "Waltier", "William", "Wyatt", "Yanis", "Yann", "Yves", "Yvon", "Zosime", "Abrial", "Abrielle", "Abril", "Adele", "Alair", "Alerion", "Amee", "Angelique", "Annette", "Antonella", "Arian", "Ariane", "Armandina", "Aubree", "Aubrielle", "Audra", "Avril", "Bella", "Berneta", "Bette", "Blaise", "Blanche", "Blasa", "Bonte", "Brie", "Brienne", "Brigit", "Cachay", "Calice", "Camille", "Camylle", "Caprice", "Caressa", "Caroline", "Catin", "Celesta", "Celeste", "Cera", "Cerise", "Chablis", "Chalice", "Chambray", "Champagne", "Chandell", "Chaney", "Chantal", "Chante", "Chanterelle", "Chantile", "Chantilly", "Chantrice", "Charla", "Charlotte", "Charmane", "Chaton", "Chemin", "Chenetta", "Cher", "Chere", "Cheri", "Cheryl", "Christine", "Cidney", "Cinderella", "Claire", "Claudette", "Colette", "Cordelle", "Cydnee", "Daeja", "Daija", "Daja", "Damzel", "Darelle", "Darlene", "Darselle", "Dejanelle", "Deleena", "Delice", "Demeri", "Deni", "Denise", "Desgracias", "Desire", "Desiree", "Destanee", "Destiny", "Dior", "Domanique", "Dominique", "Elaina", "Elaine", "Elayna", "Elise", "Eloisa", "Elyse", "Emeline", "Emmaline", "Emmeline", "Estella", "Estrella", "Etiennette", "Evette", "Fabienne", "Fabrienne", "Fanchon", "Fancy", "Fawna", "Fayana", "Fayette", "Fifi", "Fleur", "Fleurette", "Fontanna", "Fosette", "Francine", "Frederique", "Gabriel", "Gabriele", "Gabrielle", "Gaby", "Garcelle", "Gena", "Genie", "Georgette", "Germaine", "Gervaise", "Gitana", "Harriet", "Heloisa", "Holland", "Honnetta", "Isabelle", "Ivette", "Ivonne", "Jacqueena", "Jacquetta", "Jacquiline", "Jacyline", "Jaime", "Jakqueline", "Janeen", "Janelly", "Janina", "Janiqua", "Janique", "Jannnelle", "Jaquita", "Jardena", "Jeanetta", "Jermaine", "Jessamine", "Jewel", "Jewell", "Joli", "Jolie", "Josephine", "Jozephine", "Julieta", "Karessa", "Karmaine", "Klara", "Laine", "Lanelle", "Laramie", "Layne", "Layney", "Leala", "Leonette", "Lissette", "Lizette", "Lourdes", "Lucienne", "Ly", "Lyla", "Lysette", "Madelaine", "Malerie", "Manette", "Marais", "Marcelle", "Marché", "Mardi", "Margo", "Marguerite", "Marie", "Marie Claude", "Marie Frances", "Marie Joelle", "Marie Pascale", "Marie Sophie", "Marjolaine", "Marquise", "Marvella", "Mathieu", "Matisse", "Maurelle", "Maurissa", "Mavis", "Melisande", "Michelle", "Miette", "Mignon", "Mimi", "Mirya", "Monet", "Moniqua", "Monteen", "Musetta", "Myrlie", "Nadeen", "Nadia", "Nadiyah", "Naeva", "Nanon", "Natalle", "Naudia", "Nettie", "Nicholas", "Nicki", "Nicky", "Nicole", "Nicolette", "Nicolina", "Nicolle", "Nikolette", "Ninette", "Ninon", "Noelle", "Nycole", "Odelette", "Opaline", "Orane", "Orva", "Page", "Parisa", "Parnel", "Parris", "Patrice", "Peridot", "Pippi", "Prairie", "Rachele", "Rachelle", "Racquel", "Raphaelle", "Raquelle", "Remi", "Renée", "Renea", "Renelle", "Renita", "Risette", "Rochelle", "Romy", "Rosabel", "Rosiclara", "Ruba", "Russhell", "Saleena", "Salina", "Satin", "Sedona", "Serene", "Shandelle", "Shanta", "Shante", "Shariah", "Sharita", "Sharleen", "Sheree", "Shereen", "Sherell", "Sherice", "Sherry", "Sidnee", "Sidney", "Sidnie", "Sidonie", "Sinclaire", "Solange", "Solen", "Sorrel", "Suzette", "Sydnee", "Sydney", "Tallis", "Tempest", "Toinette", "Turquoise", "Veronique", "Vignette", "Villette", "Violeta", "Virginie", "Voleta", "Vonny");
            List<String> surnames = Arrays.asList("Arceneau", "Aucoin", "Babin", "Babineaux", "Benoit", "Bergeron", "Bernard", "Bertrand", "Bessette", "Blanc", "Blanchard", "Bonnet", "Boucher", "Bourg", "Bourque", "Boutin", "Bouvier", "Braud", "Broussard", "Brun", "Chevalier", "David", "Depaul", "Desmarais", "Disney", "Dubois", "Dupont", "Dupuis", "Durand", "Fortescue", "Fournier", "Garnier", "Gaudet", "Gillet", "Gillette", "Girard", "Gravois", "Grosvenor", "Lambert", "Landry", "Laroche", "Laurent", "Lefevre", "Leroy", "Leveque", "Lisle", "Martin", "Michel", "Molyneux", "Moreau", "Morel", "Neville", "Pelletier", "Petit", "Prideux", "Renard", "Richard", "Robert", "Rousseau", "Roux", "Rufus", "Simon", "Thomas");
            Iterable<Person> persons = () -> {
                return new Iterator<Person>() {
                    int counter = 40_000; //0_000;  // 40_000 yields about 20 MB of data.

                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return counter-- > 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Person next() {
                        String givenName = givenNames.get(random.nextInt(0, givenNames.size()));
                        String surname = surnames.get(random.nextInt(0, surnames.size()));
                        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
                        String description = Person.LOREM_IPSUM;
                        return new Person(givenName, surname, id, description);
                    }
                };
            };
            writer.writeValues(fileWriter).writeAll(persons);
        }
    }
}

class Person {
    // Static
    static public String LOREM_IPSUM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

    // Member variables.
    private String givenName, surname, description;
    private UUID id;

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(String givenName, String surname, UUID id, String description) {
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getGivenName() {
        return givenName;
    }

    public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
        this.givenName = givenName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{ " +
                "givenName='" + givenName + '\'' +
                " | surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                " | id='" + id + '\'' +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also created a version using univocity-parsers.

Answer (score 4):

Besides using java.nio as suggested by @Basil, simply wrapping the `FileReader` by a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) should achieve a significant speedup.

```
FileReader fileReaderMes1 = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(FECHAS[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of the solution provided by Basil, but this uses [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial):

```
public class CsvSpeed {

public static class Person {
    // Static
    static public String LOREM_IPSUM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

    // Member variables.
    @Parsed
    public String givenName, surname, description;

    public UUID id;

    @Parsed
    public void id(String id) {
        this.id = UUID.fromString(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{ " +
                "givenName='" + givenName + '\'' +
                " | surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                " | id='" + id + '\'' +
                " }";
    }
}

public List<Person> read(Path path) {
    return new CsvRoutines(Csv.parseRfc4180()).parseAll(Person.class, path.toFile(), "UTF-8", 40_000);
}

public void write(final Path path) {
    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(path.toFile(), "UTF-8", Csv.writeRfc4180());
    writer.writeHeaders("givenName" , "surname" , "id" , "description");

    int limit = 40_000;  // 40_000 yields about 20 MB of data.
    List<String> givenNames = List.of("Adrien", "Aimon", "Alerion", "Alexis", "Alezan", "Ancil", "Andre", "Antoine", "Archard", "Aurélien", "Averill", "Baptiste", "Barnard", "Bartelemy", "Bastien", "Baylee", "Beale", "Beau", "Beaumont", "Beauregard", "Bellamy", "Berger", "Blaize", "Blondel", "Boyce", "Bruce", "Brunelle", "Brys", "Burcet", "Burnell", "Burrell", "Byron", "Canaan", "Carden", "Carolas", "Cavell", "Chace", "Chanler", "Chante", "Chappel", "Charles", "Chasen", "Chason", "Chemin", "Chene", "Cher", "Chevalier", "Cheyne", "Clément", "Clemence", "Corbin", "Coty", "Cygne", "Damien", "Dandre", "Dariel", "Darl", "Dauphine", "Davet", "Dax", "Dean", "Delice", "Delmon", "Destin", "Dominique", "Donatien", "Duke", "Eliott", "Elroy", "Enzo", "Erwan", "Etalon", "Ethan", "Fabron", "Ferrand", "Filberte", "Florent", "Florian", "Fontaine", "Forest", "Fortune", "Franchot", "Francois", "Fraser", "Frayne", "Gaëtan", "Gabin", "Gage", "Gaige", "Garland", "Garner", "Gaston", "Gauge", "Gaylord", "Germain", "Germaine", "German", "Gervaise", "Giles", "Gilles", "Gitan", "Grosvener", "Guifford", "Guion", "Guy", "Guzman", "Henri", "Holland", "Hugo", "Hugues", "Hyacinthe", "Jérémy", "Jacquan", "Jacques", "Jacquez", "Janvier", "Jardan", "Jay", "Jaye", "Jehan", "Jemond", "Jocquez", "Jonathan", "Jules", "Julien", "Justus", "Karoly", "Lado", "Lafayette", "Lamond", "Lancelin", "Landis", "Landry", "Laron", "Larrimore", "Laurent", "LaValle", "Leandre", "Leggett", "Leonce", "Leron", "Leverett", "Lilian", "Loïc", "Lorenzo", "Louis", "Lowell", "Luc", "Lucien", "Lukas", "Macaire", "Mace", "Mahieu", "Maison", "Malleville", "Manneville", "Mantel", "Marc", "Marcel", "Marion", "Marius", "Markez", "Markis", "Marmion", "Marquis", "Marquise", "Marshall", "Martial", "Maslin", "Mason", "Matheo", "Mathias", "Mathys", "Matthieu", "Maxence", "Mayson", "Mehdi", "Merle", "Merville", "Montague", "Montaigu", "Monte", "Montgomery", "Montreal", "Montrel", "Moore", "Morel", "Mortimer", "Nerville", "Neuveville", "Nicolas", "Noë", "Noah", "Noe", "Norman", "Norville", "Nouel", "Olivier", "Onfroi", "Paien", "Parfait", "Parnell", "Pascal", "Patrice", "Paul", "Peppin", "Percival", "Percy", "Pernell", "Peverell", "Philipe", "Pierpont", "Pierre", "Pomeroy", "Prewitt", "Purvis", "Quennell", "Quentin", "Quincey", "Quincy", "Quintin", "Rémi", "Rafaelle", "Ranger", "Raoul", "Raphaël", "Rapier", "Rawlins", "Ray", "Raynard", "Remi", "René", "Renard", "Rene", "Reule", "Reynard", "Robin", "Romain", "Rondel", "Roy", "Royal", "Ruff", "Rush", "Russel", "Rustin", "Sabastien", "Sacha", "Salomon", "Samuel", "Satordi", "Saville", "Scoville", "Sebastien", "Sennett", "Severin", "Shant", "Shantae", "Sidney", "Siffre", "Simeon", "Simon", "Sinclair", "Sofiane", "Somer", "Stephane", "Sully", "Sydney", "Sylvain", "Talbot", "Talon", "Telford", "Tempest", "Teppo", "Théo", "Thayer", "Thibault", "Thibaut", "Thiery", "Tiennan", "Tiennot", "Titouan", "Toussaint", "Travaris", "Tyson", "Urson", "Vachel", "Valentin", "Valere", "Vallis", "Verdun", "Victoir", "Victor", "Waltier", "William", "Wyatt", "Yanis", "Yann", "Yves", "Yvon", "Zosime", "Abrial", "Abrielle", "Abril", "Adele", "Alair", "Alerion", "Amee", "Angelique", "Annette", "Antonella", "Arian", "Ariane", "Armandina", "Aubree", "Aubrielle", "Audra", "Avril", "Bella", "Berneta", "Bette", "Blaise", "Blanche", "Blasa", "Bonte", "Brie", "Brienne", "Brigit", "Cachay", "Calice", "Camille", "Camylle", "Caprice", "Caressa", "Caroline", "Catin", "Celesta", "Celeste", "Cera", "Cerise", "Chablis", "Chalice", "Chambray", "Champagne", "Chandell", "Chaney", "Chantal", "Chante", "Chanterelle", "Chantile", "Chantilly", "Chantrice", "Charla", "Charlotte", "Charmane", "Chaton", "Chemin", "Chenetta", "Cher", "Chere", "Cheri", "Cheryl", "Christine", "Cidney", "Cinderella", "Claire", "Claudette", "Colette", "Cordelle", "Cydnee", "Daeja", "Daija", "Daja", "Damzel", "Darelle", "Darlene", "Darselle", "Dejanelle", "Deleena", "Delice", "Demeri", "Deni", "Denise", "Desgracias", "Desire", "Desiree", "Destanee", "Destiny", "Dior", "Domanique", "Dominique", "Elaina", "Elaine", "Elayna", "Elise", "Eloisa", "Elyse", "Emeline", "Emmaline", "Emmeline", "Estella", "Estrella", "Etiennette", "Evette", "Fabienne", "Fabrienne", "Fanchon", "Fancy", "Fawna", "Fayana", "Fayette", "Fifi", "Fleur", "Fleurette", "Fontanna", "Fosette", "Francine", "Frederique", "Gabriel", "Gabriele", "Gabrielle", "Gaby", "Garcelle", "Gena", "Genie", "Georgette", "Germaine", "Gervaise", "Gitana", "Harriet", "Heloisa", "Holland", "Honnetta", "Isabelle", "Ivette", "Ivonne", "Jacqueena", "Jacquetta", "Jacquiline", "Jacyline", "Jaime", "Jakqueline", "Janeen", "Janelly", "Janina", "Janiqua", "Janique", "Jannnelle", "Jaquita", "Jardena", "Jeanetta", "Jermaine", "Jessamine", "Jewel", "Jewell", "Joli", "Jolie", "Josephine", "Jozephine", "Julieta", "Karessa", "Karmaine", "Klara", "Laine", "Lanelle", "Laramie", "Layne", "Layney", "Leala", "Leonette", "Lissette", "Lizette", "Lourdes", "Lucienne", "Ly", "Lyla", "Lysette", "Madelaine", "Malerie", "Manette", "Marais", "Marcelle", "Marché", "Mardi", "Margo", "Marguerite", "Marie", "Marie Claude", "Marie Frances", "Marie Joelle", "Marie Pascale", "Marie Sophie", "Marjolaine", "Marquise", "Marvella", "Mathieu", "Matisse", "Maurelle", "Maurissa", "Mavis", "Melisande", "Michelle", "Miette", "Mignon", "Mimi", "Mirya", "Monet", "Moniqua", "Monteen", "Musetta", "Myrlie", "Nadeen", "Nadia", "Nadiyah", "Naeva", "Nanon", "Natalle", "Naudia", "Nettie", "Nicholas", "Nicki", "Nicky", "Nicole", "Nicolette", "Nicolina", "Nicolle", "Nikolette", "Ninette", "Ninon", "Noelle", "Nycole", "Odelette", "Opaline", "Orane", "Orva", "Page", "Parisa", "Parnel", "Parris", "Patrice", "Peridot", "Pippi", "Prairie", "Rachele", "Rachelle", "Racquel", "Raphaelle", "Raquelle", "Remi", "Renée", "Renea", "Renelle", "Renita", "Risette", "Rochelle", "Romy", "Rosabel", "Rosiclara", "Ruba", "Russhell", "Saleena", "Salina", "Satin", "Sedona", "Serene", "Shandelle", "Shanta", "Shante", "Shariah", "Sharita", "Sharleen", "Sheree", "Shereen", "Sherell", "Sherice", "Sherry", "Sidnee", "Sidney", "Sidnie", "Sidonie", "Sinclaire", "Solange", "Solen", "Sorrel", "Suzette", "Sydnee", "Sydney", "Tallis", "Tempest", "Toinette", "Turquoise", "Veronique", "Vignette", "Villette", "Violeta", "Virginie", "Voleta", "Vonny");
    List<String> surnames = List.of("Arceneau", "Aucoin", "Babin", "Babineaux", "Benoit", "Bergeron", "Bernard", "Bertrand", "Bessette", "Blanc", "Blanchard", "Bonnet", "Boucher", "Bourg", "Bourque", "Boutin", "Bouvier", "Braud", "Broussard", "Brun", "Chevalier", "David", "Depaul", "Desmarais", "Disney", "Dubois", "Dupont", "Dupuis", "Durand", "Fortescue", "Fournier", "Garnier", "Gaudet", "Gillet", "Gillette", "Girard", "Gravois", "Grosvenor", "Lambert", "Landry", "Laroche", "Laurent", "Lefevre", "Leroy", "Leveque", "Lisle", "Martin", "Michel", "Molyneux", "Moreau", "Morel", "Neville", "Pelletier", "Petit", "Prideux", "Renard", "Richard", "Robert", "Rousseau", "Roux", "Rufus", "Simon", "Thomas");
    for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
        String givenName = givenNames.get(random.nextInt(0, givenNames.size()));
        String surname = surnames.get(random.nextInt(0, surnames.size()));
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        String description = Person.LOREM_IPSUM;
        writer.writeRow(givenName, surname, id, description);
    }
    writer.close();
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // Launch the app.
    CsvSpeed app = new CsvSpeed();

    // Write.
    String when = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toString().replace(":", "•");
    Path pathOutput = Paths.get("/tmp/persons.csv");
    app.write(pathOutput);
    System.out.println("Writing file: " + pathOutput);

    // Read.
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Path pathInput = Paths.get("/tmp/persons.csv");
    List<Person> list = app.read(pathInput);
    long stop = System.nanoTime();

    // Time.
    long elapsed = (stop - start);
    Duration d = Duration.ofNanos(elapsed);
    System.out.println("Reading elapsed: " + d);
    System.out.println("Reading took nanos per row: " + (elapsed / list.size()));
    System.out.println("nanos elapsed: " + elapsed + "  |  list.size: " + list.size());
}
}
```

Running on my machine I got the following timings:

```
Writing file: /tmp/persons.csv
Reading elapsed: PT0.230395859S
Reading took nanos per row: 5759
nanos elapsed: 230395859  |  list.size: 40000
```

It doesn't show how fast the parser can get once you factor in JIT kicking in and optimizing the code. I've changed the code to generate 400K records (resulting in a 200 MB file). Now the code prints:

```
Reading elapsed: PT0.993483883S
Reading took nanos per row: 2483
nanos elapsed: 993483883  |  list.size: 400000
```

And with 4M rows (almost 2GB of data):

```
Reading elapsed: PT7.961481755S
Reading took nanos per row: 1990
nanos elapsed: 7961481755  |  list.size: 4000000
```

Comment: Wow, it will be a good set of examples how to do that using different libraries. Good job!